# Extracting filename & modification time from ls output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have a set of files in a directory. I want to extract just the filename without the absolute path & the modification timestamp from the ls output.

```
/apps/dir/file1.txt               
/apps/dir/file2.txt
```

now from the ls output i extract out the fields for filename & timestamp

```
ls -ltr /apps/dir | awk '{print $6 $7 $8 $9}'

Sep  25  2013 /apps/dir/file1.txt  
Dec  20  2013 /apps/dir/file2.txt  
Dec  20  2013 /apps/dir/file3.txt
```

whereas i want it to be like

```
Sep 25  2013 file1     
Dec 20  2013 file2  
Dec 20  2013 file3
```

one solution can be to cd to that directory and run the command from there, but is there a solution possible without cd? I also used substr() but since filenames are not of equal length so passing a constant value to substr() function didn't work out.

Comment: Dont parse output of ls command, rather use stat. Have a read [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Don.27t_Ever_Do_These)

Comment: Even if you `cd` to the directory and run the command from there you'll still get the `.txt` on the filenames. Did you want to strip that?

Comment: yes wanted to remove that extension as well.For that if we can reach the start of the filename, we can remove it using substr().that is what i originally thought.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `GNU` find, you can do the following to get the filenames without path:

```
find /apps/dir -type f -printf "%f\n"
```

and as [Kojiro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418413/kojiro) mentioned in the comments, you can use `%t` or `%T(format)` to get modification time.

or do as [BroSlow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3076724/broslow) suggested

```
find /apps/dir -printf "%Ab %Ad %AY %f\n"
```

**Do not** try to do the following (It will break on filenames with spaces and even across different OS where `ls -l` representation has fewer/more columns:

```
ls -ltr /apps/dir | awk '{n=split($9,f,/\//);print $6,$7,$8,f[n]}'
```

Comment: Right, and you can get the mtime with %t or %T(format) as well.

Comment: Something like `find -printf "%Ab %Ad %AY %f\n"` would get exact format he wants I think.

Comment: with %t I get time format as Wed Oct  5 18:57:24.0000000000 2016. How do i change this to  yyyy-mm-dd h:m:s

Comment: find *.xml -type f  -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM:%TS %Tz %p\n">tt.txt did the trick

Answer (score 2):

[Dont](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Don.27t_Ever_Do_These) parse output of ls command, rather use stat:

```
stat -c%y filename
```

This will print the last modification time in human readable format

Or if using GNU date you could use date with a format parameter and the reference flag

```
date '+%b %d %Y' -r filename
```

You can use basename to get just the filename portion of the path:

```
basename /path/to/filename
```

Or as Kojiro suggested with [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion):

To get just the filename:

```
filename="${filename##*/}"
```

And then to strip of extension, if any:

```
filename="${filename%.*}"
```

Putting it all together:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for filename in *; do
    timestamp=$(stat -c%y "$filename")
    #Uncomment below for a neater timestamp
    #timestamp="${timestamp%.*}"

    filename="${filename##*/}"
    filename="${filename%.*}"

    echo "$timestamp $filename"
done
```

Comment: Nice point made about parsing of ls output.Thanks.
i tried with stat -c%n%y /apps/dir which gave me filenames.Although it may sound very stupid but i am not able to figure out how to use basename with this.can u help please.

Comment: You can get the `basename` with parameter expansion `"${file%.*}"`. No fork/exec required.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
files=$(find /apps/dir -maxdepth 1 -type f)
for i in $files; do
    file=$(basename $i)
    timestamp=$(stat -c%y $i)
    printf "%-50s %s\n" "$timestamp" "$file" 
done
```

Comment: Expansions of commands like `find` and `ls` are error-prone and unnecessary. Use `globstar` or the `-exec` flag to `find`.

Comment: That will break on files that contain whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reproduce the `ls` time format:

```
dir=/apps/dir
now=$(date +%s) 
sixmo=$(date -d '6 months ago' +%s)

find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -print0 | 
while read -d '' -r filename; do 
    mtime=$(stat -c %Y "$filename") 
    if (( sixmo <= mtime && mtime <= now )); then 
        fmt="%b %d %H:%M"
    else 
        fmt="%b %d  %Y"
    fi
    printf "%12s %s\n" "$(date -d "@$mtime" "+$fmt")" "$(basename "$filename")"
done |
sort -k 4
```

Assuming the GNU set of tools

Comment: oops, there was a trailing "3". fixed